# Java Card cap File loading Failure Without Any Error

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I'm trying to install a big applet (about 40 KB) applet on my Java Card. But It fails without any special error:

```
GPP:> gp -install e:\applet.cap -v -d -i

//Useless Info Censored

Reader: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
ATR: 3B8680014B4F4E4110809C
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B8680014B4F4E4110809C

A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (13ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD AID: A000000003000000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected block size: 255

***** Card info:
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
A<< (0045+2) (13ms) 9F7F2A47906C1482415046C7225077005179978161481050771180507700000000000000000000000000000000 9000
Card CPLC:
ICFabricator: 4790
ICType: 6C14
OperatingSystemID: 8241
OperatingSystemReleaseDate: 5046
OperatingSystemReleaseLevel: C722
ICFabricationDate: 5077
ICSerialNumber: 00517997
ICBatchIdentifier: 8161
ICModuleFabricator: 4810
ICModulePackagingDate: 5077
ICCManufacturer: 1180
ICEmbeddingDate: 5077
ICPrePersonalizer: 0000
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate: 0000
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID: 00000000
ICPersonalizer: 0000
ICPersonalizationDate: 0000
ICPersonalizationEquipmentID: 00000000

***** CARD DATA
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
A<< (0078+2) (18ms) 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B851086486402010366
0C060A2B060104012A026E0102 9000
Unknown tag: 4c

***** KEY INFO
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
A<< (0020+2) (13ms) E012C00401FF8010C00402FF8010C00403FF8010 9000
VER:255 ID:1 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16
VER:255 ID:2 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16
VER:255 ID:3 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16
Key version suggests factory keys
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 **************** 00
A<< (0028+2) (81ms) 00005077005179978161FF02******************************** 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: ****************
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: ****************
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with version 255 keys
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - session keys:
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:******************************** KCV: ******
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value::******************************** KCV: ******
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value::******************************** KCV: ******
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: ****************
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: BCCB4A3FE7C72337
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 BCCB4A3FE7C72337BEE53FC6E96E3CF0
A<< (0000+2) (47ms) 9000


CAP file (v2.1) generated on Fri Jul 01 12:45:19 IRDT 2016
By Sun Microsystems Inc. converter  [v3.0.2] with JDK 1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation)
Package: testPack v1.0 with AID 0102030405
Applet: TestApp with AID 010203040501
Import: A0000000620101 v1.4
Import: A0000000620201 v1.4
Import: A0000000620102 v1.4
Import: A0000000620001 v1.0
Total code size: 14249 bytes (15230 with debug)
SHA256 (code): 62692AE1D5DED46F582E9D4A70147D4673A6ADE61AB4FFBE9BF9DCFF738301AE
SHA1   (code): 987035C59C6F9D55B833982A49F6B26B42A8F1DB
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F008A7CB7FC9CFD273A 00
A<< (0019+2) (24ms) E3114F08A0000000030000009F700101C5019E 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F0036BEC9929973C2B9 00
A<< (0000+2) (32ms) 6A88
[WARN] GlobalPlatform - GET STATUS failed for 80F24002024F0000 with 6a88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F00B25292932F0404B7 00
A<< (0000+2) (38ms) 6A88
[WARN] GlobalPlatform - GET STATUS failed for 80F22002024F0000 with 6a88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F0065BAD8E85186FFAD 00
A<< (0000+2) (39ms) 6A88
[WARN] GlobalPlatform - GET STATUS failed for 80F21002024F0000 with 6a88

A>> T=1 (4+0026) 84E60200 1A 05010203040508A000000003000000000000DAEC6F17D8E21A55
A<< (0001+2) (65ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80000 FF C48237A901000FDECAFFED010204000105010203040502001F000F001F000A00290182004E09E529EE018A000003D20031000829CC040100040029040
40107A0000000620101040107A0000000620201040107A0000000620102000107A000000062000103000A0106010203040501079706004E0080030C0009041D0000093BFFFFFFFF07AB001
900CD010F011D0142019001CE01E8021E023402980306043004AF04D604EE0519052D057105BD05E406060629063F066300830000FF00010000000709E503025680090261001605E6800D0
5F50016068D80EE077D003404307C001C600C1D046A081169858D000C1D73009B00000002F7DD3E606A4D07D7
A<< (0001+2) (1s486ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80001 FF 000D003B006E1E61117B0017AD0003068E04002106A800851E046B127B0017AD00031101008E0400210770701167008D000C70687B00240303381E611
07B002CAD0003068E0400210670511E046B127B002CAD00031101008E04002107703D1167008D000C70351E61107B0030AD0003068E0400210670241E046B127B0030AD00031101008E040
0210770101167008D000C7008116B008D000C7A04207C001C60081169858D000C1D75002D00020000000D0001001D7B0036AD00031101008E0400370670187B0036AD00031101008E04003
7077008116B008D000C7A03107B0038AD00038E03000B047A03201D7500210002000000180C4D9A28B7D518D5
A<< (0001+2) (72ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80002 FF 0001000DAD017B0038048B000D700BAD017B0038058B000D7A0430198B000E3B1E75004500020000000D000100287B0017AD00038E030021043B19068
B000F19AD0003068B0010701F7B0017AD00038E030021053B191101008B000F19AD00031101008B00107A05207C001C600C1D046A081169858D000C1D75002B00020000000D0001001DAD0
0037B0011031101008D00123B7010AD00037B0013031101008D00123B7A0420198B000E3B191101008B000F197B0011031101008B00107A03307C001C600C1D046A081169858D000C1D750
01D0002000000150001000D7B0014031E3870107B0015031E387008116B008D000C7A0420A10CAE830FD9854D
A<< (0001+2) (73ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80003 FF 198B000E3B19048B000F197B001503048B00107A03321D73005A00000002000D0044004F1E610DAD027B0017058B000D70471E046B1FAD027B0036048
B000D70382E1B8B00182904116D001604558D000C7026116B008D000C701EAD027B002C058B000D7013AD027B0030048B000D7008116B008D000C7A06117B002405256108116B218D000C1
805048B0019AD027B0013031101007B001A038B001B3B7B002CAD00038E030021053BAD03AD00031101008B001DAD037B001403047B001E038B001F3B7B001A1100E07B001E0310208D002
0301D610A7B00240304387008116B208D000C7A0431190725327C001C613B1E75002F000201FA3832808C186D
A<< (0001+2) (67ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80004 FF 0000000D0001001EAD048B0022AD04190810088B0023A80102AD058B0022AD051908100C8B0023A800F1116B008D000CA800E87C001C046B517B00240
325046B0A7B00140325046A08116B218D000C1E75002F00020000000D0001001EAD048B0022AD04190810088B0023A800ADAD058B0022AD051908100C8B0023A8009C116B008D000CA8009
31F75008900020010000D0014004CAD04190810088B00256013AD048B0022AD0419100D10088B00237068AD048B00266110116B50AD048B0026558D000C7053116B50AD048B0026558D000
C7045AD051908100C8B00256013AD048B0022AD0419101110088B00237029AD058B002661FA81E55604281391
A<< (0001+2) (68ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80005 FF 0E0780001C116B228D000C7016116B40AD058B0026558D000C7008116A808D000C7A0631190725321E75007100020000000D0001003B1F10086A08116
7008D000C7B002405AD04190810088B0025387B00240525614C116B50AD048B0026558D000C703E1F100C6A081167008D000CAD051908100C8B00253BAD058B0026610E0780001C116B228
D000C7016116B40AD058B0026558D000C7008116B008D000C7A05207C001C60081169858D000C19072510146A081167008D000C19087B00270310148D00123B7A0420198B000E3B1910148
B000F197B00270310148B00107A02107C001C75002500020000000D000100130480001C70E3257112B620785F
A<< (0001+2) (72ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80006 FF 147B00140325046A08116B218D000C0580001C7A0321198B00282D1A037C001C381903048B00297A05227B002403256108116B218D000C198B00282D1
98B002A3B1A0725100A6A081167008D000C7B002B031A08100A8D0020321F610A7B00240404387008116A808D000C7A0520AD067B002B03100A8B002D1804038B00197B002B03AD001100F
6100A8D002E3BAD00031100F6038D002F3B18AD00AD078B0031198B000E3B191101008B000F19AD07031101008B00107A04201803048B001918AD00AD078B0031198B000E3B19100A8B000
F19AD071100F6100A8B00107A0632AD0219031101001A038B001B3B70122E1B8B00182904FBDC64F8BD56146B
A<< (0001+2) (73ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80007 FF 116D001604558D000C7A05107C001C046A107B00140325046A08116B218D000CAD00037B003203078D00123B7A0420198B000E3B19078B000F197B003
203078B00107A05107C001C046A107B00140325046A08116B218D000CAD00037B003303100F8D00123B7A0420198B000E3B19100F8B000F197B003303100F8B00107A0512188C003518038
908180389091803890A08110800038D0039940000377F003607110800038D0039940000217F001707110800038D0039940000217F003007110800038D0039940000217F002C100E1100800
38D00399400000B7F0038110100900B7F0011110100900B7F001A1020900B7F001E04900BFD1B512EB0542728
A<< (0001+2) (66ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80008 FF 7F001504048D003A7F0014110100048D003A7F001307048D003B7F002418110400900B87071014900B7F002718110100058D003A870018100E038D003
C870118100C038D003C870218048D003D87061807038D003E8703188F003F3D0810088C00408704188F003F3D100A100C8C00408705100A048D003A7F002B07900B7F0032100F900B7F003
3701B2C1995000016601319940000168B001831116B001E558D000C7A05308F00413D8C0042181D0441181D258B00437A0427188B004460037A7C001C076B08116B228D000C198B00282D1
A0325321A042529041A052529051A062529061A07251100FF532907082908160475014E008C6C44CDFCEC427F
A<< (0001+2) (68ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80009 FF 17FF88012F00000061001000800011008B001200AF0013009E0014010000200094002200BA002300A7002401070025010E003100C9003200D7003300C
2004000E5004100EC0042012200430128004401150045011B005000F3005100F9198B002A3B1605610A181A8C0045A800E5160504A300DF181A8C0046A800D718160516068B0047A800CC1
816058B0048A800C3181916058B0049A800B91816058B004AA800B018198B004BA800A818160516068B004CA8009D18198B004DA80095188B004EA8008E198B002A3B181A16058B004F707
F198B002A3B181A16058B00507071181A8B0051706A18198B00527063188B0053705D1819D38B8013E988435A
A<< (0001+2) (74ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000A FF 8B0054705618198B0055704F18198B0056704818198B00577041188B0058703B18198B00597034188B005A702E18198B005B7027198B000E3B193B8D0
05C8D000C191103E88B000F197B005D031103E88B0010116D008D000C7A0310AD048B005EAD058B005E7B00240403387B00240303387B00240503387A0522190625311907251100FF53321
E61171908AD07031F8D00123B18AF0A8908181F890A701E1908AD07AF081F8D00123B183D8508AF0A418908183D850A1F41890A7A0522190625311907251100FF53321E61161908AD00031
F8D00123B181F8909181F890A701D1908AD00AF091F8D00123B183D85091F418909183D85DEC4E7535D7EB5F1
A<< (0001+2) (73ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000B FF 0A1F41890A7A0110188C005F7A0829EE00310018000803019000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FEE24BE9596DB9EA
A<< (0001+2) (82ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000C FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003006400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F7B29CBD53AB9986
A<< (0001+2) (54ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000D FF 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300C800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000307D0000000000000001C0988E5D39797AC
A<< (0001+2) (53ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000E FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F2AF0956992CD99F
A<< (0001+2) (54ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000F FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009DF362EF8C2B2464
A<< (0001+2) (54ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80010 FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008B76B8B8ECEF4F41
A<< (0001+2) (53ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80011 FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002D0C66BD5BF2CFD1
A<< (0001+2) (134ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80012 FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005B7E028BBDB42BD0
A<< (0001+2) (54ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80013 FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C15ABC8BA9501A44
A<< (0001+2) (54ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80014 FF 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000AA4C06B675784615
SCardEndTransaction()
SCardDisconnect("ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0", true)

GPP:>
```

As you see above, the last APDU command that contains a block of my cap file, doesn't received any response, and so my applet can't installed. Why?

Note that I can load and install it on another card successfully. and note that if I remove some not-used big class variables, then I can load my cap file. But Why?

There are the not used variables:

```
public class FileSystem {
    public static byte[] var0= new byte[400];
    public static byte[] var1= new byte[100];
    public static byte[] var2= new byte[200];
    public static byte[] var3= new byte[2000];
    public static byte[] var4= new byte[2000];
    public static byte[] var5= new byte[2000];
    public static byte[] var6= new byte[2000];
    public static byte[] var7= new byte[2000];
}
```

Is there any limitation on cap file size other than the EEPROM capacity?

Comment: Could you tell us your card model? And then  I can have a test.

Comment: @JavaCardOS It's a KONA java card. I don't know anything more about it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have this kind of card. But anyway, the card should give the response.  Or maybe just  a UNKNOWN_ERROR.

Comment: @JavaCardOS you are welcome. Thank you. Anyway is there any limitation on cap file size other than the EEPROM capacity?

Comment: No, it has no relation to cap file size. AfaIk, the maximum cap file size allowed is 640K. So for your problem, I guess that there is some problem with your card OS.